# Associate *.ex1 Dropbox files with my app

Tags: java, android, dropbox, dropbox-api, intentfilter

```
I have a Dropbox dir with many file types,
```

among them are a few files with names like myfile.ex1

I want to write an Android App to edit myfile.ex1 
but I do not find a way to associate *.ex1 Dropbox files with my app.

My app used to work well using an intent-filter with 
scheme="file"  and pathPattern=".*\.ex1"
but it does not work anymore.

I speculate that it because Dropbox moved to 24 
So now every program with scheme="file" 
causes Dropbox to through FileUriExposedException

I speculate - again - that my app needs to use Dropbox API.

Please note that I do not want to use file chooser to select a file, 
I want to open myfile.ex1 with double click.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks
Ori